# How to stop rethink database call if cannot find result?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, rethinkdb

I run RethinkDB command with Node.js (babel) asynchronous call:

```
let user = await r.table('users').filter({key: key}).limit(1).run();
```

How can I stop the asynchronous call, if database cannot find result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `await` function means that node will wait for the asynchronous `r.table(...` command to return before continuing to the next line of code, meaning that it behaves logically as if it were synchronous code.

Your specific command should return when RethinkDB finds the first 'user' document with the specified key. There is no need to "stop" it if it cannot find a result, it will stop as soon as it (a) finds a result or (b) finished scanning the entire table.

In general "stopping" asynchronous code in node/javascript is not possible but you can limit the amount of time you'll wait for an async method. Here is an example using the [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) function.

```
/*
 * toy async function
 *
 * returns a promise that resolves to the specified number `n` 
 * after the specified number of seconds `s` (default 2)
 */
const later = (n, s=2) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(n), s*1000);
    })
}

/*
 * returns a promise that rejects with `TIMEOUT_ERROR` after the 
 * specified number of seconds `s` 
 */
const timeout = (s) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => reject("TIMEOUT_ERROR"), s*1000)
    })
}

/* 
 * Example 1: later finished before timeout
 * later resolves after 1 second, timeout function rejects after 3 seconds
 * so we end up in the `.then` block with `val == 42`
 */
Promise.race([later(42, 1), timeout(3)])
    .then(val => {
        // do somethign with val...
        console.log(val)
    }).catch(err => {
        if (err === "TIMEOUT_ERROR") {
            console.log("we timed out!")
        } else {
            consle.log("something failed (but it was not a timeout)")
        }
    });

/* 
 * Example 2 (using async/await syntax): we timeout before later returns.
 * later resolves after 3 seconds, timeout function rejects after 2 seconds
 * so we end up in the `.catch` block with `err == "TIMEOUT_ERROR"`
 */
try {
    const val = await Promise.race([later(11, 3), timeout(2)]);
    // do something with val...
} catch (err) {
    if (err === "TIMEOUT_ERROR") {
        console.error("we timed out!")
    } else {
        console.error("something failed (but it was not a timeout)")
    }
}
```